# How many weekdays, holidays or weekend days are within a dates range

Tags: python, datetime, range, days

I have a situation where I have a code with which I am processing data for operated shifts.

In it, I have arrays for start and end of shifts (e.g. shift_start[0] and shift_end[0] for shift #1), and for the time between them, I need to know how many weekdays, holidays or weekend days.

The holidays I have already defined in an array of datetime entries, which should represent the holidays of a specific country (it's not the same as [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/5-minute-guide-to-detecting-holidays-in-python-c270f8479387) and I do not seek for further more dynamic options here yet).

So basically I have it like that:

```
started = [datetime.datetime(2022, 2, 1, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2022, 2, 5, 8, 0), datetime.datetime(2022, 2, 23, 11, 19, 28)]
ended = [datetime.datetime(2022, 2, 2, 16, 0), datetime.datetime(2022, 2, 5, 17, 19, 28), datetime.datetime(2022, 4, 26, 12, 30)]

holidays = [datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 3), datetime.datetime(2022, 3, 3), datetime.datetime(2022, 4, 22), datetime.datetime(2022, 4, 25)]
```

I'm seeking for options to go thru each of the 3 ranges and match the number of days it contains (e.g. the first range should contain 2 weekdays, the second - one weekend day)

Comment: datetime objects have a `weekday` method which you could use

Comment: And how do I loop thru the periods?

Comment: `for start, end in zip(started, ended):`

Comment: @gimix, Thank you! But what is the iterator for that loop? I do not seem to be able to find such examples easily.. Actually, can you do a good example, please?

Comment: From the docs: `zip` "Returns an iterator of tuples, where the i-th tuple contains the i-th element from each of the argument sequences or iterables". So at each iteration you will have in `start` and `end` respectively one element from `started` and the corresponding element from `ended`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So based on the suggestion by @gimix, I was able to develop what I needed:

```
        for each_start, each_end in zip(started, ended):  # For each period 
            for single_date in self.daterange(each_start, each_end):  # For each day of each period

                # Checking if holiday or weekend
                if (single_date.replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0) in holidays) or (single_date.weekday() > 4):
                    set_special_days_worked(1)

                # If not holiday or weekend, then it is regular working day
                else:
                    set_regular_days_worked(1)
```